# Access Data from Ajax Call Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Jquery Ui Autocomplete.

The problem I have is the data that is being returned from my api.

```
"{"d":{"results":[],"facets":{"facet_counts":{"Town":{"":0,"londonderry":136914,"london bridge":1,"london":8983316,"london colney":1}}},"__solr_time":3473457,"__ser_time":1564,"__t_time":1421,"__count":9120232,"__max_score":1.0}}"
```

I have run it through an online parser and it is valid, but I don't know how to access the list of towns with the corresponding number next to it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: read up about associative arrays. How/why did you format the return value like that if you don't know how to deconstruct it?

Comment: I have no control over that, i would never of made it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the Town "name" and number using:

```
var test = {
    "d": {
        "results": [],
        "facets": {
            "facet_counts": {
                "Town": {
                    "": 0,
                    "londonderry": 136914,
                    "london bridge": 1,
                    "london": 8983316,
                    "london colney": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "__solr_time": 3473457,
        "__ser_time": 1564,
        "__t_time": 1421,
        "__count": 9120232,
        "__max_score": 1
    }
}
for(var prop in test.d.facets.facet_counts.Town){
     console.log(prop);
     console.log(test.d.facets.facet_counts.Town[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works which is great but when i call the same code from an ajax call it fails

$.ajax({
            url: 'town.php',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(text){
                alert(text);
                for(var prop in text.d.facets.facet_counts.Town){
                    console.log(prop);
                    //console.log(test.d.facets.facet_counts.Town[prop]);
                }
            }

Comment: I would do a console.log to ensure that the the text returning from the ajax call is in the same format (ie an object not a string). You might actually only need to do:  `for(var prop in text.facets.facet_counts.Town)` or like Mike said, do a JSON.parse before you go to the Town you need. Either way, the console.log will tell you what you need to know

Comment: Thanks for your help I finally got it to work. The Json.parse just errors. 
success: function( dat, status ) {
                        if (status == "success")response($.map(dat.d.facets.facet_counts.Town, function(item, key) {
                         if (item == 0) {
                                   return
                               }

                                return {
                                    label: key + " ( " + item + " ) ",
                                    value: key
                                }
                            }))
                         }

Comment: Hey @RobPaddock that's great! If everything worked out, I'd really appreciate it if you marked this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just run JSON.parse() on the string and then pull out the `Town` node.

```
var string; // the data string returned by API.
var dataObj = JSON.parse(string);
var Town = dataObj.d.facets.facet_counts.Town;

// access the properties as needed
var londonCount = Town.london;
var londonBridgeCount = Town['london bridge']; // need to use bracket notation to get this one
```